# Ambiguous reference to member '+'

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of floats, I want to find the index of the max 3 floats and average this. For example [20,0,9,17,31], the 3 highest are [31,20,17] and correspond to the index [4,0,3] the average of this is 3.5

My code:

```
  func calcAvgIndex(initialArray:[Float]) -> Float {

    var ammendedMaxArray = initialArray.dropFirst(2).sorted().reversed()
    let maxThreeValues = Array(ammendedMaxArray.prefix(3))
    let indexMaxThreeValues = Array(ammendedMaxArray.prefix(3).indices)
```

could it be the above line ".indicies" that I am not using correctly?

```
    var avgIndexMaxThreeValues = indexMaxThreeValues.reduce(0, +)/3
```

above line corresponds gives error Ambiguous reference to member '+'

Comment: The average of [4,0,3] is not 3.5 but 22.33333.

Comment: Yeah, so I am trying to find the average of the [4,0,3].

ie the average of the position that these max 3 values occur

Comment: Correction, I meant to write `2.33333`

Answer (score 0):

This works, although it needs a for loop.

```
var floats: [Float] = [20,0,9,17,31]
let n = 3

var tupleArray = [(Int, Float)]()
for i in 0..<floats.count {
    tupleArray.append((i, floats[i]))
}

let indices = tupleArray.sorted { return $0.1 > $1.1 }.prefix(n).map { Float($0.0) }
// [4,0,3]
let average = indices.reduce(0, +) / Float(n)
// 2.33333
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is giving me the average of the float values? I am aver the average of the indices that the 3 max values occur in

Comment: Try it out ;-).

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'ReversedRandomAccessCollection<[Float]>' (aka 'ReversedRandomAccessCollection<Array<Float>>') to expected element type 'Float'

Comment: It works if you use the example values, but I have an array that I have previously manipulated
Ie second line of my code:
  var ammendedMaxArray = initialArray.dropFirst(2).sorted().reversed()

sorry

Comment: Works just as well with `[9,17,31]`, average of `[2,1,0] = 1`. Or `[0,0,9,17,31] --> 3`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array of `Float(s)`

```
let nums: [Float] = [20, 0, 9, 17, 31]
```

### Best indexes

You can extract the indexes for the 3 max values writing

```
if nums.count >= 3 {
    let bestIndexes = nums
        .enumerated()
        .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
        .map { $0.0 }[0...2]
}
```

### Average of best values

Of course once you have the best indexes, you can get the average of the associated values. Here's the full code

```
if nums.count >= 3 {
    let bestIndexes = nums
        .enumerated()
        .sorted { $0.1 > $1.1 }
        .map { $0.0 }[0...2]

    let bestValues = bestIndexes.map { nums[$0] }
    let bestAverage = bestValues.reduce(0, +) / Float(bestValues.count)
    print(bestAverage) // 22.6667
}
```